# Is there a way to change global variables with the same name as function parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```js
let a = 0
let b = 4
let c = 0

function modify(a, b, c) {
  a = a
  b = b
  c = c
}

modify(3, 7, c);
console.log("a: " + a + " b: " + b + " c: " + c)
```

Shouldn't a, b, and c all be overwritten after calling the modify function? Why does this only return the original instantiated values?

Comment: No. Change the names of the inner variables, or attach the outer variables to the global object and access them via `window.a`, `window.b`, etc.

Comment: If the outer variables are `let`s or `const`s, then no. The best you can do is to rename your function parameters.